# How to return valid Edm.GeographyPoint for Odata Api, when input is lat and long numbers?

Tags: node.js, odata

My objective is to build a Odata REST api in js, that is consumed by Power BI.

How do I return valid `Edm.GeographyPoint` when my input is a lat and long numbers?

Or should I use a different data-type for this?

Comment: Could please share with use your code attempt?

Comment: Hi @johannchopin - I did not make any code attempt yet, because I was not able to find any information online about what shape data has to bee in, to be qualified as `GeographyPoint ` in Odata. But I'm thinking about exploring demo/public odata api's, and eventually find some data with that shape 